# SQL Server --- How to use a database alias for quick coding?

Tags: sql-server, alias

Hopefully I'm using this term correctly.

Okay as most people know if you have long table names like mylongschema.longtablename ...

You can alias the table for quick reference such as mylongschema.longtablename ml ... select ml.* ... etc.

Obviously the same goes for fields/ columns...

I'm wondering if you can alias databases the same way?

I have queries that frequently reference one of three long-named databases.

Is there a way to alias these 3 database as db1, db2, db3 ... or whatever ... at the top of my Query Editor in SSMS .... so I can just type db1.longschema.longtablename ....

Thanks!

Comment: That question is 10 years old. It included a link to a dead/ retired Microsoft product, and the suggestion of "creating" a brand new database that unlike other aliases, requires a lot higher privileges on the server. It's perhaps not possible --- but 10 years is 10 years. Hmm.

Comment: And still as correct as the day it was written.